# Routes not working when uploaded to server (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I created a site on CodeIgniter and everything works fine on XAMPP. But when I upload my file to the server the routes stopped working. I'm getting 404 URL not found error on all the page except the index page.

here is my routes.

```
$route['default_controller'] = "onlinec";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['home'] = 'serial/home/';
$route['done'] = 'serial/done/';
$route['redeem'] = 'serial/redeem/';
$route['printpage'] = 'serial/printpage/';
$route['login'] = 'serial/auth/login';
$route['logout'] = 'serial/auth/logout';
```

here is my **.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

on `http:/***/serial/home` I get a 404 URL not found error

on `http:/***/serial/` I get the page properly.

so only the `index.php` work at the moment

tried all possibilities on `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';` and my `mod_rewrite` is on in `httpd.conf`

can anyone help me out. This is a AWS Linux server.

Comment: are you trying for nice urls? Shouldn't your `.htaccess` look like this? `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [L]` (get rid of `index.php` + in codeigniters config file set `$config['index_page'] = '';`

Comment: config file is set as $config['index_page']  = ''. Tried the RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [L] and it didn't work.

Comment: what about `$config['base_url']`? is it set right?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add in htaccess Rewritebase like :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /subfolder/subsubfolder/
```

and try to set

$config['base_url'] like:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://yourwebsite.com/';
```

instead of:

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

in your config file.

Comment: this is what I meant, (`.htaccess` edit) I just forgot to delete the other chars in my comment. I hope this is the solition to this.

Comment: @ Derfder : I tried this before and I just gave it a try again and it didn't work :(

Comment: @ Kyslik : yes I did try it on the htaccess and no luck :(

Comment: @ Derfder : currently base_url is blank and it is picking up the path properly for CSS file on the index. But nothing else works..I did try it with the proper path as well....everything was working just right on Xampp and i have no idea why it's not working on the server :/

Comment: You haven't probably turn on some php modulules on this server or followsymlinks could be a problem. Try to ask the hosting support. Send them your htaccess and a link to this question. I think there is something with the server configuration.

Comment: Derfder you could be right. I'm trying this on the Amazon AWS and I did setup the server on my own. May be i didn't install some module. I tried the same thing with another server (which I setup as well :D) and it didn't work either.

Comment: Check which modules do you have enabled in your Wamp/xampp for php and then check the configuration of php via `phpinfo()` in both environments (localhost and Amazon server) and try to find what is different. I have no experience with Amazon servers, so no help on this ;(.