# Default routing does not work when deploying Codeigniter Application on Production Server

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have deployed Codeigniter Application on local wamp server it is automatically taking default controller as i type localhost/Myapplication/ but as i shifted it on server it is not taking default controller www.mysite.com/ now i get 404 page not found. I have tried both searching both of these solutions but they are not working in my case.

[Codeigniter, routing is not functioning on production server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13718549/codeigniter-routing-is-not-functioning-on-production-server)

[Routes not working when uploaded to server (CodeIgniter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17064451/routes-not-working-when-uploaded-to-server-codeigniter)

My base url is:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://Myapplication.com/';

$route['default_controller'] = "indexController";
```

.htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|uploads|css|js|lib|img|bootstrap|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: There is a conditional wrapped around your `.htaccess` meaning it only runs when the `mod_rewrite` module is enabled. Have you checked whether it is enabled on your production server? (use `phpinfo()`).

Comment: Very often this is because the file naming conventions of CI are not followed. For Controller and Model files the first letter of the file name MUST be upper case. Lower case will work on a WAMP stack but not on an actual linux server. In your case the file must be named IndexController.php  (and I'm not sure the camel-case is going to fly)